# Indexing already preprocessed bag of words with elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Is it possible to index already tokenized/preprocessed documents with elasticsearch?

My idea is simple, instead of posting ordinary text fields to elastic:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/test_index/test_type/
{
   "text":  "term1 term2 term3 term1"
}
```

I want to post already preprocessed text like:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/test_index/test_type/
{
   "text":  { "term1":2, "term2":1, "term3":1}
}
```

Or maybe even with floating values:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/test_index/test_type/
{
   "text":  { "term1":0.2, "term2":0.1, "term3":0.2}
}
```

Proximity is not important.

I think this should be possible to do by programming an analysis plugin, right?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.1/analysis.html

Any ideas how to solve this in an elegant way? I'm new to elastic and would appreciate any hints to get started.

Best, nadre.

UPDATE 1

The query should not look any different:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/test_index/test_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "text": "term1"
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the query you'll be making and what the expected results are (scoring too)?